# How I can show all records with Linq To SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables to join in a query as follows:

```
var query = (from c in Amenites_TBLs
                 join p in AmenitesContact_TBLs on c.AmenitesCodeID
                 equals p.AmenitesCodeID
                 // group c by p.AmenitesCodeID
                 into g
                 from cc in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     AmenitiesCode = Amenites_TBLs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AmenitesCodeID == cc.AmenitesCodeID).AmenitesCode,
                     CountryCode = Amenites_TBLs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AmenitesCodeID == cc.AmenitesCodeID).CountryCode,
                     Director = AmenitesContact_TBLs.Where(a => a.TypeOfContact.StartsWith("Dir")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.AmenitesCodeID == cc.AmenitesCodeID).ContactName});
```

In the Table `AmenitesContact_TBLs` there are just 3 records. In the table `Amenites_TBLs` there are 300  records but the result of the query gives only 3 records and the other 297  rows are null but the fields `AmenitiesCode` and `CountryCode` are not null in the database (they get a value).

How can I modify my query to show all 300 records?

Comment: Your query is too complicated.  If you have the proper relationships set up between tables, you shouldn't need all of those `SingleOrDefault` linqs.  For example, looking up Director should look something like this: `Amenities.Contact.Director`

Comment: @Robert Harvey,Thanks sir,i wrote down this query because in the AmenitesContact_TBLs sometime there are 6 Contacts(records) in relationship with the PK of the Amenites_TBLs so i should show those record in the same row of a datagrid,anyway thanks so much i will try to write down it following your advice.:)

Comment: Ah, I see.  There are multiple `director` s.  This might answer your question about the nulls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join

Comment: @Robert Harvey,Thanks sir, i am trying to work out this step but as you told my query a bit complex so i can not reach the result yet,anyway thanks for your directory it's a good way to work out it.

Comment: well, i tried to follow the links above but not luck, i can't show the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Amenites_TBLs.Join(AmenitesContact_TBLs , c => c.AmenitesCodeID , p => p.AmenitesCodeID,(p,o) =>
new{ AmenitiesCode = c.AmenitesCode,CountryCode = c.CountryCode,Director = p.Where(a => a.TypeOfContact.StartsWith("Dir")).ContactName });
```