# Filtering records by another table's FK to it

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

How do I filter my Linq-to-SQL query so that it only shows records that aren't referenced (via a FK) in another table?

So for example, I had two tables: TableA and TableB. TableB had a FK referencing TableA. I want to select all rows from TableA that have no records in TableB referencing it.

In raw T-SQL, I can do:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE TableA._id = TableB.fk_tablea_id)
```

In raw MySQL, I can do a left join and use the `ISNULL()` function in the where clause.

I'm not sure of the best way to do this with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Check the similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the below:

```
var ctx = new Context();
var rowAs = from TableA in ctx.TableAs
             where TableA.TableB.Count() > 0
             select TableA;
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thank you! :) I just needed to change the "> 0" to an "==".

Answer (score 1):

If you have mapping properties (e.g. EntitySet or EntityRef, differ to "one-to-many" or "one-to-one" relations) in entity TableA so you can execute next:
For EntitySet:

```
var tableAWithoutRelations= (from aRecord in TableAList where aRecord.TableB.Count()==0 select aRecord);
```

For EntityRef:

```
var tableAWithoutRelations= (from aRecord in TableAList where aRecord.TableB==null select aRecord);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  var result = from A in dbcontext.TableAs
               Where A.TableB == null
               select A;
```

Comment: That's the inverse of what I need. TableA doesn't reference TableB, but I am selecting from TableA. Infact, TableA is actually a result of other joins - my example in my post is just keeping the testcase simple.

Comment: My apologies! I misunderstood what you meant. Intellisense did actually pop up a reference to TableB from TableA even though an explicit FK field doesn't actually exist in TableA. However, it doesn't seem to return any results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `Except`-operator:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386962.aspx

```
var x = (from a in db.TableA
        select a.Column).Except(from b in db.TableB
                               select b.Column);
```