# Convert SQL to Linq, with left join

Tags: sql, linq

I need to convert this SQL to a Linq Query, but as always I can't figure it out :(

guess I need to look a Little deeper into Linq.

```
select butik.preferences.pref,isnull(butik.userpreferences.selected,0) as selected 
from butik.preferences
left join butik.userpreferences 
     on butik.preferences.id = butik.userpreferences.pref AND 
     butik.userpreferences.userid = 2
```

thanks
Christian

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL - Left Outer Join with multiple join conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171063/convert-sql-to-linq-left-join-with-null

Comment: There is a MSDN page [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) which can help you out to get better experience with LINQ by checking different examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct translation of a `left join` in LINQ. But there are plenty ways to archive what you want :)

```
from item in butik.preferences
select new
{
    Pref = butik.preferences.pref,
    IsSelected = 
        butik.userprefences.Any(up => up.pref == item.id && up.userid == 2)
        ? butik.userpreferences.First(up => up.pref == item.id && up.userid == 2).selected
        : false;
}
```

Comment: actually my code was out of context so I'm getting an nullexception

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
var Query = (from c in butik.preferences
     join v in butik.userpreferences.Where(v => v.userid == 2).DefaultIfEmpty() on c.id equals v.pref into JoinUserPref
     from v in JoinUserPref.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new
     {
         pref = c.pref,
         selected = (v.selected == null ? 0 : v.selected)
     });
```

If above code snippet is not worked then please try with below LINQPad.

http://www.linqpad.net/