# linqpad error on left join

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, linqpad

There are a bunch of examples of how to make a quasi-left join in Linq here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171063/convert-sql-to-linq-left-join-with-null), and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join)). They all point to joining a handful of parent tables into an "outer" table, then selecting from that table using `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Sounds easy enough, so I created this snippet in LinqPad:

```
dim foo = (
    from c in context.Contacts
    join p in context.Plants on c.PlantID equals p.PlantID into outer
    from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where p.PlantCode = 2
    select c.ContactName, p.PlantName
)
```

The equivalent SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT c.ContactName, p.PlantName
FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN Plants p ON c.PlantID = p.PlantID
WHERE p.PlantCode = 2
```

Looks like it should work, but LinqPad keeps stopping on the `join...into` line with this error: `')' expected.`

Am I doing something wrong? Or is LinqPad losing its mind?

Comment: I assume you're using VB.NET since you're using the `Dim` keyword. If so please tag your question to indicate VB.NET.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense. The condition 'where p.PlantCode = 2' negates the effect of the outer join and turns it into an inner join. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I wasn't debugging the query; I was debugging why my LINQ left join wasn't working. The example query was just there to demonstrate a left join that failed, and whether or not it makes sense from a query standpoint, it made enough sense from a syntax standpoint that Ahmad was able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah. It's just that there's a much easier way to do a left outer join in LINQ, but it will work only if the query is semantically valid. Would you like me fix your query and then post it?

Comment: Sure, drop it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike C#, VB.NET expects a `Group Join` clause to perform a left outer join, along with the `Group` keyword. Check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx), specifically the "Perform a Left Outer Join by Using the Group Join Clause" section.

Try the following query:

```
From c In context.Contacts
Group Join p In context.Plants On c.PlantID Equals p.PlantID Into outer = Group
From o In outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
Where o.PlantCode = 2
Select c.ContactName, p.PlantName
```

EDIT: you should use `o.PlantCode` instead of `p.PlantCode` since the `p` variable won't be in scope when querying against the grouping.

Notice the use of `outer = Group`, which is the way to alias the grouping. Alternately, if you don't care to alias it, you could write the query against `Group` directly:

```
From c In context.Contacts
Group Join p In context.Plants On c.PlantID Equals p.PlantID Into Group
From o In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
Where o.PlantCode = 2
Select c.ContactName, p.PlantName
```

Comment: Thanks, Ahmad, that almost worked with one trivial problem - once I group that table I can't refer to it by its original alias `p`; instead I have to refer to it from its group alias `o`. So instead of `p.PlantCode` or `p.PlantName` I have to use `o.PlantCode` and `o.PlantName`. The error was pretty easy to find and fix, but I figured I'd include it here in case anyone else hit it.

Comment: @mounty yep that's correct. I just wrote a comment before I saw yours.  I'll update my post.