# Join customer and payment tables where count of items in payments that year equals 2021 is zero in C# Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two tables which are customers and payments.

```
Table Customers ==> Columns [CustomerId, ...other customer info].
Table Payments ==> Columns [PaymentId, CustomerId, Year, ...other payment info]
```

How can I get customers that haven't paid this year. I have no idea what I need.

```
import System.Linq;
var result = from customers in context.Customers 
join payments from context.Payments 
on customers.CustomerId equals payments.CustomerId
where payments.Year == 2021 into paymentsCount
where paymentsCount.count == 0;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171063/convert-sql-to-linq-left-join-with-null

Comment: Does your answer need to be in the SQL-like syntax, or can it use method-based syntax?

Comment: Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have proper navigation properties:

```cs
var query = context.Customers
    .Where(c => !c.Payments.Any(p => p.Year == 2021));
```

If there is no proper navigation property:

```cs
var query = context.Customers
    .Where(c => !context.Payments.Any(p => p.CustomerId == c.CustomerId && p.Year == 2021));
```