# linq2sql join select data that is not in another table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Please do not respond using lamba. I have found similar threads but still need help.

I am trying to display the names from the employees table that are not employees of the currently selected manager.

My two sql tables are structured like this but this is fake data

```
Employees:   
           pk      name     
           1      bob
           2      sam
           3      greg
           4      kip
           5      jill
           6      kelly
           7      chris


ExpenseTeamMembers: 

           pk      expMgrPk     empPk     
           1         7          2
           2         7          5
           3         7          1
           4         3          6
           5         3          4
```

So if the the current selected (mgr variable) is 3 I want to get the names of all empPks in the employees table except for 6, 4. (kelly, kip) Right now unselectedEmps = sam, jill, bob instead of all 5 of other names from the employees table.

```
var unselectedEmps = (from u in db.employees
                      join o in db.expenseTeamMembers on u.pk equals o.empPk
                      where o.expMgrPk != mgr 
                      select u.name).ToList();

                lstAvailable.DataSource = unselectedEmps;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our extended discussion, I think what you want is this.

```
from u in db.Employees
where !(from e in db.ExpenseTeamMembers
        where e.expMgrPk == selectedMgr.pk
        select e.empPk).Contains(u.pk)
select u.Name
```

Comment: The top one is not working. It is still retrieving the records I dont want. The outer join works but it is outputting {name=  in front of every record. Is there a way I can get rid of that without parsing? Thanks!!

Comment: @osiris355 Try it now, with the modified final select.

Comment: I found a bug after I add a record to the expenseTeamMembers table. I will update tonight or tomorrow after i have some more time to debug.

Comment: Its pretty odd. The first time I add a record to the expenseTeamMembers table I fire this query and it works flawlessly. As soon as I try to add the same employee to a different manager it no longer refreshes correctly. I can add a different employee to a different manager fine. its just when I try to use the same emp with  two different expMgrPks. I've been trying to figure it out but am struggling to come up with a solution.

Comment: To be more specific the second time i add an employee it still shows the employee I have already added. So it shows the full list. Let me know if I need to give a better description

Comment: @osiris355 I've been playing around with the query in LinqPad, adding employees, changing their managers, etc, and it seems to work every time for me.  That means the issue probably lies elsewhere, or I don't completely understand.  Perhaps you are missing a DataBind after you've changed the datasource?  To explore it more, I'd really need to see some more code.

Comment: No the data should be rebinding because it is firing your query after every record i add or change the manager in the combo box. Is there a cleaner way i can submit my code to you than through comments? Email or something? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @osiris355 You can zip it and email to either of the addresses in my profile.  I may not be able to look at it until tomorrow.

Comment: @osiris355 Take a look at the current answer, or your email.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing an inner join when you actually need a left outer join

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join)

Comment: Still getting same results with                                   var unselectedEmps = (from u in db.employees
                      join o in db.expenseTeamMembers on u.pk equals o.empPk into sr
                    from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where x.expMgrPk != mgr 
                      select u.name).ToList();

Comment: I think you want to swap the order, you want everything from employees, so that should be in the 2nd spot, expenseTeamMembers should go first

Comment: No same result. var unselectedEmps = (from  o in db.expenseTeamMembers
                                          join u in db.employees on o.empPk equals u.pk into sr
                                          from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          where o.expMgrPk != mgr 
                                          select x.name).ToList();

Comment: Even if I delete my where clause now it still only searches the expenseTeamMembers table and not the employees table

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following and it is giving the correct output. Please try it:

```
List<Employees> emps = new List<Employees>();
        emps.Add(new Employees { PK = 1, Name = "bob" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { PK = 2, Name = "sam" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { PK = 3, Name = "greg" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { PK = 4, Name = "kip" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { PK = 5, Name = "jill" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { PK = 6, Name = "kelly" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { PK = 7, Name = "chris" });

        List<ExpenseTeamMembers> etm = new List<ExpenseTeamMembers>();
        etm.Add(new ExpenseTeamMembers { empPK = 2, ExpMgrPK = 7, PK = 1 });
        etm.Add(new ExpenseTeamMembers { empPK = 5, ExpMgrPK = 7, PK = 2 });
        etm.Add(new ExpenseTeamMembers { empPK = 1, ExpMgrPK = 7, PK = 3 });
        etm.Add(new ExpenseTeamMembers { empPK = 6, ExpMgrPK = 3, PK = 4 });
        etm.Add(new ExpenseTeamMembers { empPK = 4, ExpMgrPK = 3, PK = 5 });

        var query = from t in
                        (
                            from emp in emps
                            join o in etm on emp.PK equals o.empPK into j
                            from k in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new { Name = k == null ? string.Empty : emp.Name })
                    where t.Name != string.Empty
                    select t.Name;
```

Comment: I am not working with a collection. I am working with sql data

Comment: I have taken collection only to display how the query can be written. You can replace the emps with db.Employee and so on.

Comment: Im trying to get your code to work but I am having some problems. Since I am searching for pk's dont I need to weange the string.empty to some how check for an integer? Also I dont see how this will work consider there is no checking for the expense Manager