# Linq with LEFT Join

Tags: c#, linq

```
        var query =
            (from Contact con in e.Results
             from ContactPhoneNumber phn in con.PhoneNumbers
             from ContactEmailAddress email in con.EmailAddresses.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where con.DisplayName.Contains(txtContasctSearch.Text)
             select new person()
             {
                 displayName = con.DisplayName,
                 displayEmail = (email.EmailAddress == null ? String.Empty : email.EmailAddress),
                 displayPhone = phn.PhoneNumber
             }).ToList();
```

The `EmailAddress` field is not always available.  However, I would still like to bring it back if it exists.  I want to mimic a Left Join however, the code above returns an error.

Any ideas?

The error I'm receiving is:

```
 System.NullReferenceException occurred
   _HResult=-2147467261
    _message=NullReferenceException
     HResult=-2147467261
    Message=NullReferenceException
    Source=wpChoreList
    StackTrace:
       at wpChoreList.personSetup.<Contacts_SearchCompleted>b__8(<>f__AnonymousType1`2    h__TransparentIdentifier1)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: _What does the error say?_

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking wrong value for null:

```
displayEmail = (email.EmailAddress == null ? String.Empty : email.EmailAddress),
```

email should be empty, not email.EmailAddress, try changing that line to this one:

```
displayEmail = (email == null ? String.Empty : email.EmailAddress),
```

Comment: That was it!  Dang something so simple...  Thank you.  I will award as answer as soon as it lets me.