# Is there a better solution for performing Linq group join?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two very large tables, both have over 10K recodes in them.  I need to use Linq to query from  these two tables.  See below example, You can see I need to use group join.

[image]

Below is my query, it works.  But it takes about 6-7 minutes to finish. TableA has over 10K records. TableB has more records than tableA.

```
from a in tableA
join b in tableB on new {ID = a.OrderID, Name = a.Option} 
             equals new{ID = b.OrderID, Name = b.SelectedOption} into jgroup
select new{
    OrderID = a.OrderID,
    SelectedOption = a.Option,
    SelectedOptionValue = 
             jgroup.Select(g => g.SelectedOptionValue).SingleOrDefault()
}
```

Is there a better solution to make this faster using linq to SQL.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the SelectedOptionValue selected to `jgroup.FirstOrDefault().SelectedOptionValue`?

Comment: Do you have an appropriate index on Table B?

Comment: hi @It'sNotALie, thanks. But it does not make a differece.

Comment: Most likely the problem is not with the LINQ query itself. You should try the same query inside Sql Server and post the Execution Plan here so we can take a look and suggest index improvements

Comment: is this linq to objects, or with a query provider?  If the latter, what is the query provider?

Comment: thanks @tucaz, I know the LINQ query doesn't have problems, what I want to know is a better solution for query a large data using group join.

Comment: @Lin there is a better way. Indexing. But in order to help you with it that we need to see a query plan

Comment: @tucaz I haven't seen my query plan yet, you gave me a good idea. Let me check it, if I can't figure it out, I'll post it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The linq statement might not be translating optimally. I think a more explicit left join syntax would work best

```
var query = 
  from a in tableA
  from b in tableB.Where(x => a.OrderID == x.OrderID && a.Option == x.SelectedOption).DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new
  {
    OrderID = a.OrderID,
    SelectedOption = a.Option,
    SelectedOptionValue = b.SelectedOptionValue
  };
```

Comment: This isn't a left join, it's a cross join, and will perform quite a bit worse on larger data sets (in addition to simply not returning the same results).

Comment: @Servy - This gets translated to a left join in Linq-to-Sql. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join

Comment: If there are multiple matching entries in the second table for a given item in the first table your code has two output rows, the OP's code will have one.  They are clearly not producing the same type of join.

Comment: @Servy - The OP uses `SingleOrDefault`. OP would use `FirstOrDefault` if there was a chance for multiple matches.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the query provider to have different SQL representations for those two methods; I'd expect it to treat them identically.