# Convert SQL (LEFT OUTER JOIN) to LinQ

Tags: sql, linq

Could someone please convert the below raw sql to linq ?

```
_sql= " SELECT tbl_book.*, tbl_time.tt_scope, tbl_time.tt_time "+
      " FROM tbl_time "+ 
      " LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_book ON tbl_time.tt_time = tbl_book.book_time "+
      " AND (tbl_book.ppt_id=@ppt_id AND tbl_book.fct_id=@fct_id "+
      " AND tbl_book.book_date=@book_date)";
```

Comment: Just a hint: `LEFT OUTHER JOIN` = `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: See [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL Left Outer Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if

```
var ppt_id_param = "@ppt_id";
var fct_id_param = "@fct_id";
var book_date_param = "@book_date";
```

be our params, and your context be this:

```
TestEntities DBContext = new TestEntities();
```

your linq query is like:

```
var query = (from time in tbl_time
             join book in tbl_book on time.tt_time equals book.book_time 
                 into joinedList
             from book in joinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where book == null ? 
                 true :
                 (
                      book.ppt_id == ppt_id_param &&
                      book.fct_id == fct_id_param &&
                      book.book_date == book_date_param &&
                 )
             select new {

                 time.tt_scope,
                 time.tt_time
                 book
             })
             .ToList();
```