# LEFT JOIN with OR condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to write following T-SQL in LINQ:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.Name
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON (T1.ID = I2.ID1 OR T1.ID = T2.ID2)
```

An OR-join would look like this in LINQ:

```
T1.Join(T2, t1=>new{}, t2=>new{}, (t1,t2)=>new{ID=t1.Id, t2=t2}).Where(o=>o.Id == o.t2.Id1 || o.Id==o.t2.Id2);
```

But that query is an INNER JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN.
Some kind of LEFT JOIN would look like this:

```
T1.GroupJoin(T2, t1 => t1.Id, t2 => t2.Id1, (t1, t2) => new { Id = t1.Id, Name1 = t2.Select(t => t.Name) }).DefaultIfEmpty()
  .GroupJoin(T2, o => o.Id, t2 => t2.Id2, (i, j) => new { Id = i.Id, Name1 = i.Name1, Name2 = j.Select(t => t.Name) }).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

This query produces correct results, but makes 2 joins instead of 1. Or is it really equivalent to original T-SQL?

Does anybody know how to rewrite this query better?

Comment: Why do you have two GroupJoins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer from a similar question gives us an easy way to write `LEFT JOIN`s:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739738/1869660

```
var query = from t1 in T1
            from t2 in T2.Where(tt2 => (t1.ID == tt2.ID1) || (t1.ID = tt2.ID2))
                         .DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { t1.ID, t2.Name }
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve this with single linq, try using cross join

```
var results = (from a in test1
from b in test2
where a.ID == b.ID1 || a.ID == b.ID2
select new {x = a.ID, y = b.Name});
```

Comment: This will result in an INNER JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score -2):

```
var LeftJoin = from emp in ListOfEmployees
               join dept in ListOfDepartment
               on emp.DeptID equals dept.ID into JoinedEmpDept 
               from dept in JoinedEmpDept.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new                          
               {
                   EmployeeName = emp.Name,
                   DepartmentName = dept != null ? dept.Name : null                          
               };
```