# Linq, join and null how to check a value

Tags: c#, linq, windows-store-apps

I try to join two collection into one. If my second is empty I just need a null value, here is my code (it's correct if `com` is not empty)

```
    var tmp = List{ Elem {long UserID; string tmpContent} };
    var com = List{ Comment{long UserID; string Content} } ;

    var res = from t in tmp
              group t by t.UserID into g
              join c in com on g.Key equals c.UserID
              select new AnswerSet(new List<Answer>(g), c.Content);
```

I would like to get `AnswerSet(g, Content)` ou `AnswerSet(g, null)` the problem, I guess, is with `g.Key equals c.UserID` when com is empty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739738/397817 DefaultIfEmpty()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what you want is a [left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx). you can do that by using `join into` instead of just `join`.

```
var res = from t in tmp
          group t by t.UserID into g
          join c in com on g.Key equals c.UserID into j
          from subc in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new AnswerSet(new List<Answer>(g), subc != null ?subc.Content : null);
```