# SQL limitation equivalent in linq

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I am looking for a linq equivalent of a SQL query bellow.

```
select * from tableA as A
left join tableB as B on A.Id = B.Id
left join tableC as C on B.Id = C.Id
left join tableD as D on C.Id = D.Id and D.OrderId = B.OrderId
```

I am most interested how to correctly limit results using this expression:

```
 and D.OrderId = B.OrderId
```

C# code

```
var data = from a in tableA

join innerB in tableB on a.Id equals innerB.Id into INNERB
from b in INNERB.DefaultIfEmpty()

join innerC in tableC on b.Id equals innerC.Id into INNERC
from c in INNERC.DefaultIfEmpty()

join innerD in tableD on c.Id equals innerD.Id into INNERD
from d in INNERD.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(p=>p.OrderId == b.OrderId)
```

The linq returned results from db doesn't match SQL query. 
Any hints are appreciated if you could explain me how to use a variable from a previous join table that is applied for each row.

I've tried also but the compiler throws an error that "the name of b doesn't exist in current context":

```
join innerD in tableD.Where(p=>p.OrderId == b.OrderId) on c.Id equals innerD.Id into INNERD
from d in INNERD.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer for a simpler `LEFT JOIN` syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739738/1869660

Your query would be:

```
var data = from a in tableA
           from b in tableB.Where(x => x.Id == a.Id)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
           from c in tableC.Where(x => x.Id == b.Id)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
           from d in tableC.Where(x => (x.Id == c.Id) && (x.OrderId == b.OrderId))
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
           select ...
```

Comment: In my case it worked. Thanks a lot. However I cannot always use this syntax. "There is an issue with using this syntax when joining nullable values or strings. Since the where statement doesn’t know about the cardinality relationship (1-Many, 0-1 – Many, etc), Entity Framework adds an additional check where the nullable value is not null to allow for join cases where both sides have a null value" from http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Left-Outer-Joins-in-LINQ-with-Entity-Framework