# Entity Framework: SELECT From Where ID NOT IN

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I know this could be easy question but I spent hours trying to figure it out with no luck!

I want to achieve the following SQL Command in Entity Framework:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE RowID NOT IN (
SELECT SomeID FROM Table2 Where SomeID is not null)
```

I tried the following (Asp.Net C#):

```
var SomeIDs = db.Table2.Where(n => n.SomeID != null).Select(x => x.SomeID);
var query = (from a in db.Table1
             where !(SomeIDs.Contains(a.RowID))
             select a;
```

It works fine in small database, but in production db it takes forever then time out!

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What SQL is generated for that?

Comment: Let me guess, in production `SomeIDs` contains many more items.

Comment: The LINQ query should generate exactly the same `NOT IN` or equivalent `NOT EXISTS` SQL query. Can you show the output of `query.ToString()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `AsNoTracking`, it might help you if you are not using the returned objects to update data in database

```
Table1.where(x => !someIds.conatins(x.id)).AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: I think your answer is my solution because after I added .AsNoTracking(); It really became much faster even in the live database!

Thank you :)

Comment: @AKO nice to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using .DefaultIfEmpty(), [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join).

```
var query = from a in db.Table1
            join b in SomeIDs
                on a.RowID equals b.SomeID into c
            from b in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where b == null
            select a;
```