# Linq To Objects Outer Join

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Im trying to use LINQ to query Objets. I'm doing the following:

```
Dim myList As Generic.List(Of MyItem) = (From ThisItem In LinqToSqlObject.Items _
                                         Join Folder In LinqToSqlObject.Folders _
                                         On Folder.Id Equals Item.Id _
                                         Join thisParentItem As Item In LinqToSqlObject.Items _
                                         On thisParentItem.Id Equals Item.ItemId _
                                         Select New MyItem With {.ItemName = Item.Name, _
                                         .ParentItemName = thisParentItem.Name}).ToList
```

This however will not return any item that has a ParentItemId of null.
I am trying to do a left join so as to return all "Item" regardless of whether it has a parent or not. I am aware that this is feasible in C# by adding an "into X" on the join, and selecting from X.DefaultIfEmpty(), this however does not appear to work in VB.Net.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Sql: Multiple left outer joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx) example.

Edit: Oops missed the vb.net requirement, sorry.

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins/267632#267632) to a similar question.

Edit of the Edit (I'm on a roll)

Posted a link to the wrong answer, but same question.

The vb.net answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins/268991#268991)

Comment: Hi @Mike, I have seen this (excellent website), but as stated in the question, i am aware that this is possible in C# (as per the code in your link), but i cant get it to work in VB.Net.

Comment: @Ben - sorry, I did miss that in the first pass. I've updated the answer with a vb.net based link. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Ben, did it again, posted the wrong link. I'm fixing it. Just not my night.

Comment: No problem, we've all had those days. Thanks for the link, worked perfectly, @Jdidu got there a bit quicker though.