# Left outer join in LINQ out of scope in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq

I have 2 tables

**Item**(Id, Description, …, cnyID)

**Company**(companyID, companyDesc, …)

I have queries that return lists of these 2 tables, some of these queries take parameters.

```
lstItemBarcodes = ItemBAL.SelectBarcodesList(txtItemCode.Text.Trim())
lstCompanies = CompanyBAL.GetAllCompanies()
```

I have a datagridview that is bound to items, the problem is that it returns the *CnyID* and not the description.

So I am  trying this in order to get the *companyDesc*

```
    Dim result = (From supplier In lstItemBarcodes 
                  Group Join company In lstCompanies On supplier.cnyID Equals company.CompanyID Into Group
                  Select {supplier, company}
                  ).ToList
```

But it is not compiling, I am getting `Name 'company' is either not declared or not in the current scope.`

I need all the fields of the first list and description from the second.

Comment: You forgot something like this `.. From company In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()` exactly before `select`.

Comment: Would you please elaborate, it removes the error, but I still cannot access the `companyDesc` from company.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand query syntax in VB.NET. It is what needed for C#.

Comment: It is working for VB too.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5629794/10646316)