# LinQ - Left Join Two DataTables

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I am wondering if anyone can help me.
I am new to LINQ and still trying to understand how it fits together.

I have a simple left join query in SQL, returning all transactions that are on table 1 that do not exist in table 2.  Both tables are identical in structure.

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.DealReference = Table2.DealReference
WHERE (((Table2.DealReference) Is Null));
```

Can someone please guide me, how to achieve the same in LinQ.

I am using the following DataTables:

```
    Dim currentDataTable = _DataTable1.AsEnumerable
    Dim previousDataTable = _DataTable2.AsEnumerable
```

I am looking to have the results output back into a datatable.

Thanks

BM

Comment: You can read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins.

Answer (score 0):

1) `Linq-To-DataTable` is a subset of `Linq-To-Objects` and assumes that the data is already in memory. So if you want a scalable solution you might want to have  a look at `Linq-To-Sql` which queries the database directly.

2) Your join is not a simple left join but a left-outer join. You can achieve that for example with this query:

```
Dim rows = From r1 In _DataTable1
           Group Join r2 In _DataTable2
           On r1.Field(Of String)("DealReference") Equals r2.Field(Of String)("DealReference")
           Into DataGroup = Group
           From row In DataGroup.DefaultIfEmpty
           Where row Is Nothing
           Select r1
Dim tblresult = rows.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. Both DataTables have already been filled and are in memory so this solution looks relevant. Im stepping through your code, however, I am getting an error at the following part after looping through a few times. Where row.IsNull("DealReference")  Table 1 has 3 transactions in it "Brian1", "Brian2" and "Brian3".  Table 2 has 2 transactions in it.  "Brian1" and "Brian2".  It looks like it falls over when it gets to the 3rd entry.

Comment: @Brian: Edited my answer. `Where row Is Nothing` should work.

Comment: Still getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Hi

Can anyone help?

Thanks