# Multiple Joins in Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got some help earlier with adding a join to a query. I now realize that I actually need to add multiple joins in the same query, but I've tried numerous ways (based on the original join) but keep getting errors.

I have a model called SchemeName -

```
namespace TRS.Models
{
    public class SchemeName
    {
        [Key]
        public int SchemeNameID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Scheme Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Benefit> Benefits { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and multiple models for employee benefits such as the following two that each have SchemeIDs -

```
namespace TRS.Models
{
    public class Pension
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public bool PensionRequired { get; set; }
        public int PensionSchemeNameID { get; set; }
        public int PensionProviderID { get; set; }
        public int PensionBenefitLevelID { get; set; }
        public decimal PensionEmployerCost { get; set; }
        public decimal PensionEmployeeCost { get; set; }

        public virtual PensionBenefitLevel PensionBenefitLevel { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TRS.Models
{
    public class LifeAssurance
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public bool LifeAssuranceRequired { get; set; }
        public int LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID { get; set; }
        public int LifeAssuranceProviderID { get; set; }
        public string LifeAssuranceBenefitLevel { get; set; }
        public decimal LifeAssuranceEmployerCost { get; set; }
        public decimal LifeAssuranceEmployeeCost { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller I have the following -

```
var trs = db.Users
                .Join(db.SchemeNames,
                user => user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID, 
                schemeName => schemeName.SchemeNameID,
                (user, schemeName) => new { User = user, SchemeName = schemeName })
                .Where(a => UserIDs.Contains(a.User.UserName))
                .Select(a => new TRSViewModel
            { 
                UserName = a.User.UserName,
                FirstName = a.User.UserDetails.FirstName,
                LastName = a.User.UserDetails.LastName,
                Salary = a.User.UserDetails.Salary,
                PensionSchemeName = a.SchemeName.Name,
```

Which works great for displaying the PensionSchemeName but I also need to display the LifeAssuranceSchemeName (and others) but as I mentioned keep getting errors. I thought I would just need to add an additional Join with the details of the LifeAssuranceSchemeName so I tried adding -

```
                var trs = db.Users
                .Join(db.SchemeNames,
                user => user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID, 
                schemeName => schemeName.SchemeNameID,
                (user, schemeName) => new { User = user, SchemeName = schemeName })
                .Join(db.SchemeNames,
                la => la.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID,
                schemeName => schemeName.SchemeNameID,
                (user, schemeName) => new { User = user, SchemeName = schemeName })
                .Where(a => UserIDs.Contains(a.User.UserName))
                .Select(a => new TRSViewModel
```

but this gives me an error -

Error   10  'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Pension' and no extension method 'Pension' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea how I can add these additional Joins?

Comment: Are both the `PensionSchemeName` and `LifeAssuranceSchemeName` values in the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those joins have not been properly chained.

In the second join, the second argument refers to the outer collection. This will be the projected anonymous type from the first join `new { User = user, SchemeName = schemeName })` .

Assuming there is a property LifeAssurance on the User class, I then guess you want the do the second join based on that property from the user object, something like this:

```
var trs = db.Users
            .Join(db.SchemeNames,
                 user => user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID, 
                 schemeName => schemeName.SchemeNameID,
                 (user, schemeName) => new { User = user, 
                                             SchemeName = schemeName })
            .Join(db.SchemeNames,
                 x => x.User.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID,
                 schemeName => schemeName.SchemeNameID,
                 (x, schemeName) => new { User = x.User, 
                                          PensionSchemeName = x.SchemeName, 
                                          LifeAssuranceSchemeName = schemeName })
            .Where(a => UserIDs.Contains(a.User.UserName))
            .Select(a => new TRSViewModel{
                          UserName = a.User.UserName,
                          FirstName = a.User.UserDetails.FirstName,
                          LastName = a.User.UserDetails.LastName,
                          Salary = a.User.UserDetails.Salary,
                          PensionSchemeName = a.PensionSchemeName.Name,
                          LifeAssuranceSchemeName = a.LifeAssuranceSchemeName.Name
            });
```

This could be written on query syntax as (probably easier to read):

```
var trs = from user in db.Users
          join pensionSchema in db.SchemeNames 
               on user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID equals pensionSchema.SchemeNameID
          join lifeAssuranceSchema in db.SchemeNames 
               on user.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID equals lifeAssuranceSchema.SchemeNameID
          where UserIds.Contains(user.UserName)
          select new TRSViewModel{
                      UserName = user.UserName,
                      FirstName = user.UserDetails.FirstName,
                      LastName = user.UserDetails.LastName,
                      Salary = user.UserDetails.Salary,
                      PensionSchemeName = pensionSchema.Name,
                      LifeAssuranceSchemeName = lifeAssuranceSchema.Name }
```

Finally, take into account these are inner joins so any user without pension or life assurance schema will not be returned. If you want left joins, you can do something like the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins) (Although I guess you dont need this as otherwise expressions like `user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID` will throw a NullReferenceException if there are users without Pension)

```
var query =
      from user in db.Users
      from pensionScheme in db.SchemeNames
              .Where(s => s.SchemeNameID == user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID)
              .DefaultIfEmpty()
      from lifeAssuranceScheme in db.SchemeNames
              .Where(s => s.SchemeNameID == user.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID)
              .DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new { User = user, 
                   Pension = pensionScheme, 
                   LifeAssurance = lifeAssuranceScheme}
```

I have quickly tested those queries using the following code with in memory collections, but they should be translated correctly to SQL by entity framework:

```
public class SchemeName
{
    public int SchemeNameID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Pension
{
    public int PensionSchemeNameID { get; set; }
}

public class LifeAssurance
{
    public int LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Pension Pension { get; set; }
    public LifeAssurance LifeAssurance { get; set; }
}

public static class db
{
    public static IEnumerable<User> Users = new List<User>() { 
            new User { Name = "User 1", 
                        Pension = new Pension { PensionSchemeNameID = 1 }, 
                        LifeAssurance = new LifeAssurance { LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID = 2 } },
            new User { Name = "User 2", 
                        Pension = new Pension { PensionSchemeNameID = 1 }, 
                        LifeAssurance = new LifeAssurance { LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID = 2 } },
            new User { Name = "User 3", 
                        Pension = new Pension { PensionSchemeNameID = 1 },
                        LifeAssurance = new LifeAssurance { LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID = -999 }},
            new User { Name = "User 4", 
                        Pension = new Pension { PensionSchemeNameID = -999 }, 
                        LifeAssurance = new LifeAssurance { LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID = 2 } }
    };
    public static IEnumerable<SchemeName> SchemeNames = new List<SchemeName>() { 
                new SchemeName{ SchemeNameID = 1, Name = "Scheme 1"  },
                new SchemeName{ SchemeNameID = 2, Name = "Scheme 2"  }
    };
}

    private void Run()
    {
        var innerJoinQuery1 = db.Users
                    .Join(db.SchemeNames,
                            user => user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID,
                            schemeName => schemeName.SchemeNameID,
                            (user, schemeName) => new
                            {
                                User = user,
                                SchemeName = schemeName
                            })
                    .Join(db.SchemeNames,
                            x => x.User.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID,
                            schemeName => schemeName.SchemeNameID,
                            (x, schemeName) => new
                            {
                                User = x.User,
                                PensionSchemeName = x.SchemeName,
                                LifeAssuranceSchemeName = schemeName
                            })
                    .Where(a => a.User.Name.StartsWith("User "))
                    .Select(a => new 
                    {
                        UserName = a.User.Name,
                        PensionSchemeName = a.PensionSchemeName.Name,
                        LifeAssuranceSchemeName = a.LifeAssuranceSchemeName.Name
                    });

        var innerJoinQuery2 = from user in db.Users
                     join pensionSchema in db.SchemeNames
                        on user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID equals pensionSchema.SchemeNameID
                     join lifeAssuranceSchema in db.SchemeNames
                        on user.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID equals lifeAssuranceSchema.SchemeNameID
                     where user.Name.StartsWith("User ")
                     select new
                               {
                                   UserName = user.Name,
                                   PensionSchemeName = pensionSchema.Name,
                                   LifeAssuranceSchemeName = lifeAssuranceSchema.Name
                               };

        var lefJoinQuery =
                      from user in db.Users
                      from pensionScheme in db.SchemeNames
                              .Where(s => s.SchemeNameID == user.Pension.PensionSchemeNameID)
                              .DefaultIfEmpty()
                      from lifeAssuranceScheme in db.SchemeNames
                              .Where(s => s.SchemeNameID == user.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceSchemeNameID)
                              .DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new
                      {
                          UserName = user.Name,
                          PensionSchemeName = pensionScheme != null ? pensionScheme.Name : "No Pension",
                          LifeAssuranceSchemeName = lifeAssuranceScheme != null ? lifeAssuranceScheme.Name : "No Life Assurance"
                      }; 

        foreach (var result in innerJoinQuery1)
            Print(result.UserName, result.PensionSchemeName, result.LifeAssuranceSchemeName);

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var result in innerJoinQuery2)
            Print(result.UserName, result.PensionSchemeName, result.LifeAssuranceSchemeName);

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var result in lefJoinQuery)
            Print(result.UserName, result.PensionSchemeName, result.LifeAssuranceSchemeName);

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private void Print(string user, string pension, string lifeAssurance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("User: '{0}', Pension: '{1}', Life Assurance: '{2}'", user, pension, lifeAssurance));
    }
}
```

Which produces the expected output:

> For the first inner join query
>
> > User: 'User 1', Pension: 'Scheme 1', Life Assurance: 'Scheme 2'
> >
> > User: 'User 2', Pension: 'Scheme 1', Life Assurance: 'Scheme 2'
>
> For the second inner join query
>
> > User: 'User 1', Pension: 'Scheme 1', Life Assurance: 'Scheme 2'
> >
> > User: 'User 2', Pension: 'Scheme 1', Life Assurance: 'Scheme 2'
>
> for the left join query
>
> > User: 'User 1', Pension: 'Scheme 1', Life Assurance: 'Scheme 2'
> >
> > User: 'User 2', Pension: 'Scheme 1', Life Assurance: 'Scheme 2'
> >
> > User: 'User 3', Pension: 'Scheme 1', Life Assurance: 'No Life Assurance'
> >
> > User: 'User 4', Pension: 'No Pension', Life Assurance: 'Scheme 2'

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Now working and you are right about the query syntax being a lot easier to read.