# Second join statement incorrectly filtering records

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having trouble with a LINQ query where I am trying to join 3 tables, one of which acts as a filter. When I run the query with just one of the joins I get the expected number of records back but when I add in the second join the query is filtering additional records out that I don't want it to. The 2 queries are pasted below...can anyone see where I'm going wrong here? Thanks!

With a single join (expected results):

```
                 Dim Report = From Filter In FilterTable _
                              Join EDTK In eDTKBase _
                                On Filter.PLI_Code Equals EDTK.eDTK_PLI _
                              Select Filter.PLI_Code, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_Instance, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_PLI_Name, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_PDP_Code, _
                                     EDTK.PDD_PDP_Description
```

With 2 joins:

```
                  Dim Report= From Filter In FilterTable_
                              Join EDTK In eDTKBase _
                                On Filter.PLI_Code Equals EDTK.eDTK_PLI _
                              Join PLI In ProdBase _
                                On Filter.PLI_Code Equals PLI.Siebel_PLI _
                              Select Filter.PLI_Code, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_Instance, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_PLI_Name, _
                                     PLI.Siebel_PLI, _
                                     PLI.Siebel_PLI_Name, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_PDP_Code, _
                                     PLI.Siebel_PDP_Code, _
                                     EDTK.PDD_PDP_Description
```

OK so I changed the query to one using left joins but I still get records filtered out; is there maybe a problem with the way my joins are written?

```
 Dim EDTKMultPDPtoPLIRpt = From Filter In EDTKMultPDPtoPLIFilter _
                              Group Join EDTK In eDTKBase _
                                On Filter.PLI_Code Equals EDTK.eDTK_PLI _
                              Into g = Group _
                              From EDTK In g _
                              Group Join PLI In ProdBase _
                                On EDTK.eDTK_PLI Equals PLI.Siebel_PLI _
                              Into h = Group _
                              From PLI In h _
                              Select Filter.PLI_Code, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_Instance, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_PLI_Name, _
                                     PLI.Siebel_PLI, _
                                     PLI.Siebel_PLI_Name, _
                                     EDTK.eDTK_PDP_Code, _
                                     PLI.Siebel_PDP_Code, _
                                     EDTK.PDD_PDP_Description
```

Comment: Any chance you need to join `PLI` by more then one field? From both of the initial tables?

Comment: Please provide a reduced test case. If we copy-paste your above code, it won't work in our empty projects.

Comment: @Yuriy - No the single field is sufficient

Comment: @ Neolisk - Sorry I'm a bit of a noob...what do you mean by reduced test case?

Comment: @StephenT Oh I am sorry I think I misunderstood. When you add the second query you're getting *less* data, correct? and you want to keep all of it even if second query doesn't have related records

Comment: @ Yuriy - Correct, the second join returns less records than the one with the single join. It should return the exact same number of records just including additional fields.

Comment: Do you need to do a left join?  In other words, are you certain there is a record in ProdBase for every PLI_Code that appears in FilterTable?  If not, that would explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like you need a LEFT JOIN.

If there are values in FilterTable.PLI_Code that do not appear in ProdBase.Siebel_PLI then you will not get those combined rows back on an Inner Join.

You can test it easily in SQL by just joining the table, counting the results and then changing 'JOIN' to 'LEFT JOIN'.  If you get more results (you should have one for every row in FilterTable) with the Left Join then that's your problem.

If you establish that's the case, you can modify your linq query to do that, or perhaps you will need to add more records to ProdBase.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that was the problem. However when I update my query with left joins I'm still having records filtered out. Maybe there's a problem with my syntax? I've pasted my new query up top.

Comment: My left joins in linq use .DefaultIfEmpty() which I don't see in your code.  Try this link on how to do multiple left joins in Linq.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins?rq=1