# Linq outer join on non-nullable field

Tags: linq, outer-join

Using some logic mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971086/590719), I'm using this code to perform outer joins on a few tables.  I know that one of the three joins will yield a MyField value. However, in my select statement, I'm calling a constructor, and I only want to use the MyField value that is not null.

```
public static MyResult GetMyResult(string MyString)
{
    var result = (from w in context.TABLE_ONEs
        from a in context.TABLE_TWOs.Where(x => x.field1 == w.field1).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from l in context.TABLE_THREEs.Where(y => y.field1 == w.field1).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from n in context.TABLE_FOURs.Where(z => z.field1 == w.field1).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new MyResult(w.someField, 
            w.someOtherField, 
            (a.date ?? l.date ?? n.date))
        ).First();

        return result;
    }
```

However, I'm getting compile errors saying, "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'".  This works fine for nullable data-types, such as string, but not on this "date" field.

Do you know of a way to fix this, aside from changing the database column to nullable DateTime?

Comment: Wont the **DateTime** field default to **DateTime.MinValue** when it isn't set in the database? In that case something ugly like this would work: **(a.date != DateTime.MinValue ? a.date : (l.date != DateTime.MinValue ? l.date : n.date))**

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena: I tried this solution and I got System.Reflection.TargetOfInvocationException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following isn't quite clean, but should work.

```
date = (DateTime?) (a != null) ? a.date : (l != null) ? l.date : (n != null) ? n.date : null
```

Instead of a nullable DateTime you use MinDate so it remains a value type.