# LINQ to SQL multiple tables left join

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

i have a stored procedure with dynamic query which s working fine in my case but when it is not creating a return type with edmx. for that i am trying to use linq for the same stored procedure but getting a bit difficult as i am a newbie. can anyone help me on this.

here is my code

SQL:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetProductList_SearchForManyToOne] 
@orgid bigint,   
 @ownerid bigint,
 @OrderList nvarchar(MAX)
AS

BEGIN    
-- -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
-- -- interfering with SELECT statements.\  
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = ''      
  SET @Sql = 'SELECT ProductID = ii.ProductId,
   InvItemId = convert(bigint,0),
   Name = p.Name,
   PrimaryImageID = p.PrimaryImageID,ProductNumberLabel = p.ProductNumberLabel,ProductNumber = p.ProductNumber,
   category = isnull(c.Name,''''),
   qty = ISNULL((SUM(ii.[QuantityOnHand]) - SUM(ii.[QuantitySold])), 0.00),
   SalePrice= ISNULL(p.SalePrice, 0.00),
   EnteredQuantity=(case when (ISNULL((SUM(ii.[QuantityOnHand]) - SUM(ii.[QuantitySold])), 0.00) > 1) then 1.00 else ISNULL((SUM(ii.[QuantityOnHand]) - SUM(ii.[QuantitySold])), 0.00) end)
   ,Discount=0,u.UnitName,
   u.UnitID     
   FROM dbo.[InventoryItems] ii  
   Left Join dbo.[Product] p on ii.ProductId = p.ProductId  and p.activestatus=1
   Left Join dbo.[category] c on p.DefaultCategoryId = c.CategoryId 
   Left Join dbo.[Unit] u on p.UnitId=u.UnitId and u.Activestatus=1 
   WHERE p.OrganizationID = '+ CAST(@orgid AS VARCHAR(15))+'
   AND ii.ActiveStatus = 1   
   AND p.ActiveStatus = 1  
   AND p.IsDisabled = 0  
   And p.CanSale = 1
   AND ii.InventoryID IN (' + @OrderList + ') 

   group by ii.ProductId, p.Name, p.PrimaryImageID, p.ProductNumberLabel, p.ProductNumber, c.Name,p.SalePrice,u.unitname,u.UnitID  
   having ISNULL((SUM(ii.[QuantityOnHand]) - SUM(ii.[QuantitySold])), 0) > 0  
   Order by p.ProductNumber, p.Name, c.Name '
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

and here what i am trying is:

```
var qu= from ii in db.InventoryItems                            
                                join p in db.Products 
                                     on ii.ProductID equals p.ProductID into pGroup
                                from mr in pGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                join u in db.Units
                                     on mr.UnitID equals u.UnitID into uGroup
                                from ur in uGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                join c in db.Categories
                                     on mr.DefaultCategoryID equals c.CategoryID into cGroup
                                from cr in cGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where mr.ActiveStatus == 1 && mr.OrganizationID == orgID && ii.ActiveStatus == 1
```

from now onwards i cant understand how to do that.

Comment: Call ToString on qu and see what is the difference after that try to fix it. If you produce smaller problem than this it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Download [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) it shows you the SQL produced by your query so you can compare this to what you expect. (I have no affiliation to this, I just find it incredibly useful).

Comment: Below link can help you                                                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins?rq=1