# Linq group join and where statement on property of the joined table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, join

So I believe I have found out that `group join` is a `left outer join` and that is what I need. But I need to check if the joined tables property is `null`. But I haven't got it working yet.

So I basically need the equivalent of this query in Linq Entity Framework

```
SELECT
    id, test, test2 
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON 
    table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table2.example = NULL;
```

I have tried to do this with lambda but without any success yet. I can't seem to get the hold of the `table2` property example for the `where` statement.

Comment: Can you post the code that you already tryed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to Sql: Multiple left outer joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins)

Answer (score 1):

You can flow this example using LINQ Extension Method (GroupJoin):

```
    Table1.GroupJoin(Table2,
                    x => x.ID,
                    y => y.ID,
                    (tbl1, tbl2) => new {Table1=tbl1, Table2 =tbl2.DefaultIfEmpty()})
                    .SelectMany(
                    tbl => tbl.Table2.Where(t2 => t2.example == null).Select(x => new
                    {
                        id= tbl.Table1.ID,
                        test = tbl.Table1.Test,
                        test2 = tbl.Table2.Test
                    }))ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Linqer is a SQL to LINQ converter tool. It helps you to learn LINQ and convert your existing SQL statements.

Not every SQL statement can be converted to LINQ, but Linqer covers many different types of SQL expressions.

Lets assume you have Table1 and Table2 in an EF dbcontext.

```
from Table1 in context
from Table2 in context
    .Where(t2=> t2.ID == Table1.ID && t2.example == null).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
     id= Table1.ID
    ,test = Table1.Test
    ,test2 = Table2.Test
}
```